# Why does the debt-to-income ratio not affect credit?

Tags: credit-score, debt-to-income-ratio

Lenders obviously *care* about the debt-to-income ratio, since it can influence whether one gets a mortgage or other types of loans. This makes sense: taking on new credit is more of a risk for people with more existing bills to pay and can increase the likelihood of non-payment, and people with a low debt-to-income history show experience with keeping their debt at levels that they can pay.

However, the debt-to-income ratio is not included in most major credit scores in the United States, unlike credit utilization, credit mix, account length, and so forth. Why is this?

Comment: Do the companies producing credit scores _know_ people's income? My feeling is they don't.

Answer (score 3):

The credit history is just that - *credit* history. It records your track record of repaying your debts. Did you miss payments? Did you leave an unpaid debt that had to go to collections? Dis you sell a house for less than a non-recourse loan on it? Were you in a bankruptcy? Are there judgements against you?

All these are the questions that your credit report attempts to answer and rate. Your income is not part of that discussion. It may or may not be relevant to lenders. For example, for most credit cards - income to debt ratio wouldn't matter much since the credit is revolving and you pay a very high interest. Vast majority of credit card holders have way too much credit compared to their income (all the smart people leave that credit unused, which is why debt to credit ratio matters). For most mortgages, on the other hand, just knowing the income to debt ratio would be meaningless - they'll want to know what kind of income it is, how reliably you've been getting it so far, and what are the chances you'll continue getting it.